# Can I fit a logistic regression on a model using mutually exclusive input variables?

Tags: regression

I have a binary outcome variable for which I want to estimate predicted probabilities. I have about 5 input variables that I want to use to predict this outcome. Among those input variables are two variables that cannot exist together. One of these is a dummy variable (0/1), the other is numeric, where values take NA when that event does not happen but take a magnitude value when it does. In other words, when the first of these variables is 1, the other will appear as NA; when it is 0, the other will have a numeric value capturing the magnitude of the value in question. Is it possible to estimate this model using a regular logistic regression, or is there some other method that is better suited for this type of problem?